# H18 Error: Django app Media Upload failing on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, file-upload, amazon-s3

Our Django App is failing media upload. This has been an off-and-on issue for us for a while. however, for about a week now, it's been consistently failing to upload media. Our media files are stored on S3.

On inspection, the uploaded files were found in the S3 buckets... However, the logs display the message below while the app throws an Application error...

[image: Screen Shot 2017-06-14 at 2.47.30 PM.png]

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer on GitHub (https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/840)

Hi, we hit this issue in production using Flask + Gunicorn + Heroku and couldn't find a cause or a workaround.

For one particular POST request with POST parameters, the request would fail with an H18 error (sock=backend) in Heroku's router indicating that the server closed the socket when it shouldn't have.

We started decreasing the response size of that failing endpoint until we narrowed it down to around the 13k mark. If we sent less than 13k, the response would always work. If we sent more than 13k, the response would almost always not work.

Code to reproduce this is available at https://github.com/erjiang/gunicorn-issue - just deploy the repo to Heroku as is and follow the instructions in the README.